# C# Use camera microphone to record

Tags: c#, microphone, directsound

I am making an application that record sound from a microphone and i don't know how to get all the microphones installed on the pc... i've tried with DirectSound but that gives me just the Audio Card MicIn. So, how can i get all the microphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article looks like it might get you started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

And it looks like you can view VLC's source code for some additional inspiration:

http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=88002

Hope this helps!